# CSS3 Custom Cursor

Tags: css

I'm having trouble making a custom cursor for my website. The following CSS doesn't work:

```
.body {
    cursor:url('http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_LQHm8-mbqNo/THeo64IPnkI/AAAAAAAAABU/N6OwdhNA0Gs/s320/cursor.png'), auto;
}
```

Do you have any idea why this might be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the source you are using for the image allow hotlinking?

Comment: Try referencing to a local image, does that work?

Comment: Did you define a class in your document named "body", or did you mean to use "body { ... }" instead?

Comment: Another possibility: Is your site using https? If so, you'll need to use https for external assets like this, otherwise the browser may block it as a security risk.

Answer (score 2):

You need change image size. Try width 20px and height 30px. Here you can do it http://picresize.com/edit , then place image in () like (image.png) and it's complete.

```css
body {
  cursor: url(http://ani.cursors-4u.net/anime/images13/ani1229.png), auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
<h1>Hello!</h1>
<p>There are new cursor.</p>
</body>
```